# onchange function not getting triggered in custom wordpress plugin

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I am facing a problem in calling a onchange() function in an external js file in my Custom Wordpress Plugin.
**Enqueing Script**

```
function ajaxschool_enqueuescripts()
{
    wp_enqueue_script('ajaxschool', ASSFURL. '/js/ajaxschool.js', array('jquery'));
    wp_localize_script('ajaxschool', 'ajaxschoolajax', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php')));

}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', ajaxschool_enqueuescripts);
```

Here is my **HTML Code**

```
echo '<div id="HCS-qsCityWrap" class="HCS-qsFieldWrap">';
    global $wpdb;
    $city_results = $wpdb->get_results ("SELECT * from wp_gj73yj2g8h_hillsborough_city_list;");
    echo '<select id="city_id" name="city_name" class="HCS-qsInput HCS-qsSelectInput">';
    echo '<option value="">Choose a City</option>';
    foreach ( $city_results as $result ) {
    echo '<option value="'.$result->city_id.'">'.$result->city_name.'</option>';
    }
    echo '</select>';
    echo '</div>';
```

jquery **ajaxschool.js code**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
 $('#city-id select').on('change', function(){
    alert("Function Called");
});
});
```

Comment: `$('#city-id select')` is wrong. Just `$('#city-id')`

Answer (score 2):

Try like this.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    $(document).on('change','#city_id', function(){
        alert("Function Called");
    });

});
```

Comment: Still doesn't work.. I am using the same file to execute a functionality...even with that, i faced similiar issue like I could not trigger button onclick jquery function, just for an alternative i changed the button with a link and in html gave a onclick=:somefunction()

Comment: HCS-qsCityWrap is in loop?

Comment: please make sure you included the jquery library. Did you see any error on console?

Comment: I cannot see any error on console...here is my web link http://accessrealtytampa.com/hillsborough-county-homes-school/ . I am trying to apply this select onchange on first dropdown

Comment: change this #city-id to #city_id

Answer (score 1):

Selector `'#city-id select'` means:

> Find some element with id `city-id`. Then find a `<select>` element among it's descendants.

But your `<select>` already has id `city-id`. So finding `<select>` inside a `<select>` is useless. Just reduce your selector to:

```
$('#city-id').on('change', function(){
    alert("Function Called");
});
```

Comment: Still doesn't work.. I am using the same file to execute another functionality...even with that, i faced similiar issue like I could not trigger button onclick jquery function, just for an alternative i changed the button with a link and in html gave a onclick=:somefunction()

Answer (score 1):

From your given html code, the id of the select is **`city_id`** not `city-id`.

So the jQuery must be

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('#city_id').on('change', function(){
        alert("Function Called");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#city_id').change(function(){
        alert("Function Called");
    });
});
```

Try this, hope it'll help